# How to draw translucent/transparent textures with lwjgl?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, textures, transparency

I've spent a lot of time trying to find out how to draw transparent textures onto the screen, however my code doesn't seem to work. So far, only textures that are fully opaque are drawn normally (like in the background of the image below). As you can see in the image below, the transparent parts are getting filled in by a red color instead of being transparent. (I used paint.net to draw transparency, is that right?)

EDIT (with new code as well): Now the transparent parts have gone away, but there is a small red outline like in the image below where there are translucent pixels. How do I make it render as transparent too? Also, I don't understand why setting *glClearColor*'s alpha doesn't change anything.

[image]

I set the *glClearColor* to red, however the alpha is 0.

```
GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Here is my code for drawing textures(using *slick-util*):

```
        PNGDecoder decoder = null;
        try {
            decoder = new PNGDecoder(new FileInputStream(Main.projectPath + path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());

        try {
            decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4, PNGDecoder.RGBA);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        buffer.flip();

        int id = GL13.glGenTextures();

        GL13.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

        GL13.glPixelStorei(GL13.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        GL13.glTexParameterf(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL13.GL_NEAREST);
        GL13.glTexParameterf(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL13.GL_NEAREST);
        
        width = decoder.getWidth();
        height = decoder.getHeight();
        GL13.glTexImage2D(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL13.GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL13.GL_RGBA, GL13.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        
        GL13.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL13.GL_RGBA);
        GL13.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL13.GL_RGBA);
        GL13.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL13.GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        GL13.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL13. GL_NEAREST);

        this.texture = new Texture(id);
        this.textureID =  id;
```

Here is my code for rendering the texture to the screen:

```
public void renderMesh(Mesh mesh) {
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVAO());
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.getIBO());
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mesh.getMaterial().getTextureID());
    shader.bind();
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    shader.unbind();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I would like to know what is incorrect of this code.

EDIT: Here is my init and shader code as well:
Initialization code:

```
window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, isFullscreen ? GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : 0, 0);
    
    if (window == 0) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Window wasn't created");
        return;
    }
    
    GLFWVidMode videoMode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    windowPosX[0] = (videoMode.width() - width) / 2;
    windowPosY[0] = (videoMode.height() - height) / 2;
    GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(window, windowPosX[0], windowPosY[0]);
    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_TEXTURE);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();   
    
    
    createCallbacks();
    
    GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);
    
    GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 460 core

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;
in vec2 textureCoord;

out vec4 passColor;
out vec2 passTextureCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    passColor = color;
    passTextureCoord = textureCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 passTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{             
    vec4 texColor = texture(texture1, passTextureCoord);
    if(texColor.a < 0.1)
        discard;
    FragColor = texColor;
}
```

Comment: Are you anywhere enable blending? `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`? If so, please add that and your shader to the question.

Comment: transparency is order-dependent. you draw these trees first, blending against the red background, and then add the "background" image, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with the red outlines I think you need to set the threshold for discarding the pixels a bit higher.

My suspicion is that the painting program didn´t draw pixels entirely transparent. E.g. if a pixel would have an alpha value of 0.2 it wouldn´t be discarded and despite being a bit transparent. Then the renderer tries to blend it with the background, because it isn´t in the order.

The pixels are probably red because the you set the background color to red:

```
GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

So the solution to this would either be to sort the objects from back to front or increase the discarding threshold in your fragment shader to something like 0.9.